# Changing Perl @ISA dynamically?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to incorporate an old version of a module dynamically

We currently have a class that uses a module...very simplified for the question

```
use Modulev1;

our @ISA = qw( Modulev1 );

sub new {
    my $class = shift or return
    my $self = $class::SUPER::new( @_ ) or return;

    $self->do_stuff();

    $self;

}
```

We have an old module that has the same method names/variables, but different coding for a different version api on a remote server, that I'd like to 'plug in' as an option.

```
use Modulev1;
use Modulev2;

our @ISA = qw( Modulev1 );

sub new {
    my $class = shift or return;
    my %args = @_;

    if( $args{ use_version_2 } ) {
        @ISA = qw( Modulev2 );
    }

    my $self = $class::SUPER::new( \%args ) or return;

    $self->do_stuff();

    $self;

}
```

This seems to work in one way (gets results), but it feels like the wrong approach, and I get some warnings like 'Constant subroutine module::variable redefined at /opt/perl/lib/5.30.1/Exporter.pm' which makes sense, as it's trying define those constants twice in each version, and that feels wrong and prone to future bugs.

So there's 2 main questions

1) Is there any issue with reassigning @ISA, like I have.

2) Is there a better clean way to try and use 2 versions of the same module in code, rather than this ugly error prone hack ? It feels like I should somehow be keeping the modules more separate, so they can't try and do things like redefine constants.

Edit: I've also tried dynamically adding the 'use module' case, but that seems to have the same issue, and feels like it would be inefficient as this gets called a lot of times.

Edit: Just to clarify, the script may call the object multiple times within the same run, but use different versions.

Comment: Can you use `require` instead of `use` to load the modules dynamically?

Comment: Interesting. Oddly I've tried require instead of 'use' at the top of the file (rather than nested in the 'new' sub which I think is what you were meaning? This seems to get rid of the errors. I'm a little confused by that though...is that just a warnings thing, as it's moved away from compile time ? Are there performance issues with moving it to run time loading (if that's correct).

Comment: Not sure I can tell an appreciable difference in speed tbh, so this may well be a good option if there are no other downsides. Feel free to pop it in as an answer.

Comment: Actually, not sure this is working if this is called several times within the same run and version changed with subsequent times (but seems to if varied and just tested once, altering it each time).

Comment: Ignore, looks good.

Comment: Note that `use` is a compile-time statement and will execute in the parsing phase regardless of positioning (except relative to other compile-time statements); `require` is a runtime statement. The other major difference is that `use` will also import from the module, which sounds like it's causing the conflict when both modules export the same functions to your package. Exporting to a subclass is completely unnecessary since methods are resolved via `@ISA`, so object classes often should not do it at all.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with changing `@ISA` dynamically like this is that you are applying that change to the entire class, not just the one instance that was requested with the `use_version_2` parameter. This may not matter if it's only expected that the object will only ever be used once in a program (i.e. it's a singleton) but it's not a good practice regardless. The other minor issue is that whenever `@ISA` is changed, the method cache is reset (since method calls are likely to subsequently resolve to different subroutines).

Two alternative options I would consider would be to make a different subclass for each "version", or to leverage roles with [Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny) and [With::Roles](https://metacpan.org/pod/With::Roles), which lets you dynamically apply a set of behavior to a specific object by essentially creating a subclass on the fly.

For example you could make "Modulev1" and "Modulev2" into two roles, and apply the one requested, this would also handle loading the module.

```
# first role module
package Modulev1;
use Role::Tiny;
# subroutines to be composed in
1;

# second role module
package Modulev2;
use Role::Tiny;
# subroutines to be composed in
1;

# user of roles
use With::Roles;
...
if ($args{use_version_2}) {
  $self->with::roles('Modulev2');
} else {
  $self->with::roles('Modulev1');
}
```

Or you could create two separate classes, and put the common code of the two versions into a role they would use statically using [Role::Tiny::With](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny::With) (this is similar to how you would use an "interface" in some other languages, except that it can also supply implementations).

```
package ModuleCommon;
use Role::Tiny;
requires 'foo', 'bar'; # require these functions to be implemented by versioned class
sub baz { }
1;

package Modulev1;
use Role::Tiny::With;
sub foo { }
sub bar { }
with 'ModuleCommon';
1;
```

Then you would make the determination of which class to use externally (like with a wrapper function), rather than inside a constructor of either one.

Comment: That's a great point about the change to the entire class, that's the stuff I was pondering. I guess there's no way for a 'local' isa change somehow ? I couldn't seem to get roles working, I just get "Can't determine class or role type", if there is any more to your example that would need to be changed to make it work, it may make it click in my brain how to develop the solution.

Comment: @Ian Your roles need to use Role::Tiny (or a wrapper like Moo::Role or Moose::Role, if you use one of those object systems), this is what defines them as a role package. Roles cannot be instantiated, but instead can be dynamically applied in this way, or statically with Role::Tiny::With.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `@ISA` is a package (global) variable. You can't change it on a per-instance basis. Also remember that inheritance is designed for an object that is a more restricted notion of a more general idea, rather than a way to dispatch. Working against that is sure to bring tears.

Even if you could localize it, you could only ever have one object working at a time because the localization of a package variable is actually dynamic. The change exists everywhere in the program until the dynamic scope cleans up. You don't want those sorts of synchronization issues.

I think there are two cleaner ways to deal with this.

1. Give each module the same (or close) interface, and return their object directly. Your `new` then is a "factory" that returns an object of a class appropriate to the arguments. If you can only have one of these active in the program at any time, then you should consider some way to make a singleton (or just make everything a class method).
2. Have an "adapter" class contain an object of the right versioned module and translate method calls to the versioned object that's part of the instance. When you run into a method that isn't in the versioned object, you have a way to complain about. This is useful for communicating API and interface changes in warning messages.